# How to combine these two columns to one timestamp, in Teradata? Thanks

Tags: sql, timestamp, teradata

[image: need help to combine date and time into 1 column only. For example: combine 'date1' and 'time1' to timestamp, like 7/17/2019 17:30:00]

Need help to combine date and time into 1 column only. For example: combine 'date1' and 'time1' to timestamp, like 7/17/2019 17:30:00.

'date1' format is [Date]

'time1' format is [Char(6)]

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way is probably:

```
Cast((theDate (FORMAT 'yyyymmdd')) || theTime AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'yyyymmddhhmiss')
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
select
  cast(date1 as varchar(20)) || ' ' || time1
from yourTable
```

Comment: Can you try to see if you can add ':' in timestamp? I used: CONCAT(CONCAT(Trim(BOTH FROM shp_dlvr_dt),' '),Trim(BOTH FROM shp_dlvr_tm)), but this has no ':" neither.